# Click events in DevExtreme DxDataGrid buttom column don't trigger

Tags: javascript, vue.js, devextreme, dx-data-grid

I have the following code:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <DxDataGrid :dataSource="viewerRoles">
            <DxColumn data-field="name"
                      caption="Ansicht" />
            <DxColumn data-field="description"
                      caption="Beschreibung" />
            <DxColumn type="buttons">
                <DxButton icon="preferences"
                          @click="test" />
            </DxColumn>
        </DxDataGrid>
        <button @click="test"></button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { DxDataGrid, DxColumn, DxButton } from 'devextreme-vue/data-grid'

    export default {
        name: 'Test',
        components: {
            DxDataGrid, DxColumn, DxButton
        },
        data() {
            return {
                viewerRoles: []
            }
        },
        async created() {
            const svcResp = await this.$http.get('Settings/ViewerRoles');

            if (svcResp.status === 200)
                this.viewerRoles = svcResp.data;
        },
        methods: {
            test() { alert('') }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The strange thing is, that if I click the HTML `<button>`, the browser shows the alert. But on the `<DxButton>`, it doesn't. As far as I can see, there are no errors in the debugging console.

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

Change the `DxButton`'s `@click` to `:on-click` instead so your code should be something like below:

```
<DxColumn type="buttons">
  <DxButton icon="preferences"
            :on-click="test" />
</DxColumn>
```